# Machine learning methods that maximize true positive rate

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for a method that maximizes true positives only.

Put another way, what I am looking for differs from usual classification in the sense that I would like the learning method to identify a region where the "positive" labels are as dense as possible, regardless of other positives (of course there must be a minimum expected size for this region, otherwise, any small enough region around a specific point would do the job).

An option that I have would consist in thresholding the probabilities coming from a usual classifier (with a high threshold), but I would like to know whether there is any method *designed* with this objective in mind.

Comment: Just label everything positive?

Comment: I second the notion of labeling everything as positive. If there is no penalty for missing a negative case, this is the only way I can defend. (I have trouble imagining a case where this would apply, however.)

Comment: third; machine learning engineers seem to know just enough statistics to be fatally dangerous.